# Flask with debugging results in "Address already in use"

Tags: python, windows, flask

The following code runs fine (in Jupyter notebook):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
#app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route("/")

def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

uncommenting `app.config["DEBUG"] = True` and running results in error: `Address in use`. I tried changing port, but without any luck.

Update: I am on Windows 7

Comment: Use lsof command to check the port where it is getting used. Check the process if not required kill it and re run the flask code.

Comment: @error404 Thank you, I am on Windows so `lsof` does not work. I already tried `app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port=800x,debug=True)` with different values of `x`

Comment: On Windows try `netstat -ano` to get the PID related to each listening port. You can look up the PID in Task Manager (add PID column in View->Select Columns).

Comment: @soundstripe. I tried `app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port=5000)` and checked  `netstat -ano` 127.0.0.1:5000 did not show up.